# Multiple Radio Buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to make a quiz, like the current BuzzFeed and Zimbio. I am sorry if this is a question that is already on here, but from my searching, I can't seem to find my answer. So, you are only allowed to select one answer. Depending on what they pick, the answer is linked to sentence.

Here's my javascript:

```
// JavaScript Document
var trait=true;
while(trait){
if(humor===true)
    {
        console.log("Answer1");
        }
if(intelligence===true)
    {
        console.log("Sentence 2");
        }
};
```

While my form looks like this:

```
<p>What personality trait matters most?</p>

<input type="radio" name="trait" value="humor">Humor
<br/><input type="radio" name="trait" value="intelligence">Intelligence
<br/><input type="radio" name="trait" value="freewill">Free Will
<br/><input type="radio" name="trait" value="passion">Passion for Everything
<br/><input type="radio" name="trait" value="detail">Attention to Detail
```

I have only the first two questions coded but I'm sure I'm doing it wrong. I know I will use a while loop. I'm just confused on what to do from here. Thanks!

Comment: wht exactly you wants to do

Comment: I want to have the input from the radio button print the text, depending on the input to the question. I want the text to be printed at the end though

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input[type='radio']").click(function(){
   switch(this.value){
      case "humor": 
          console.log("answer1"); 
          break;
      case "intelligence": 
          console.log("sentence2"); 
          break;
      default:
          console.log("default");
   }
});
```